# Why are products of spheres integrable?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

Let $n+1 \geq 3$ be an integer and $p + q = n$. Inside the unit sphere $\mathbf{S}^{n+1}$ the product
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{S}^p(\sqrt{p/n}) \times \mathbf{S}^q(\sqrt{q/n}) = \{ (X,Y) \in \mathbf{R}^{p+1} \times \mathbf{R}^{q+1} \mid \lvert X \rvert^2 = p/n, \lvert Y \rvert^2 = q/n \}.
\end{equation}
defines an embedded minimal hypersurface.

They are known to be integrable, in the sense that every Jacobi field on $\Sigma_{p,q} = \mathbf{S}^q(\sqrt{p/n}) \times \mathbf{S}^q(\sqrt{q/n})$ is generated by a one-parameter family of minimal hypersurfaces.

**Question.** How is the integrability of $\Sigma_{p,q}$ proved? Is integrability known for any other embedded minimal hypersurface in $\mathbf{S}^{n+1}$?

The only reference I know for a proof of the integrability of $\Sigma_{p,q}$ is a paper of Allard and Almgren [1], which is however hard to read. (They also establish that product of three or more spheres - which however have higher codimension - are not integrable.)

[1] William Allard, Frederick Almgren Jr. On the Radial Behavior of Minimal Surfaces and the Uniqueness of their Tangent Cones. *Annals of Mathematics*, Second Series, Vol. 113, No. 2 (Mar., 1981), pp. 215-265.

Comment: You can use separation of variables to explicitly find all Jacobi fields in this case and then just verify that they correspond to ambient isometries. One place to find this is the Inventiones paper of Simon and Solomon. As far as I know, it is a relatively famous open question in the area if there are any minimal hypersurfaces in S^n that are nonintegrable (in higher codimension there are examples, like you say). I think that integrability is proven for the m,1 Lawson surfaces by the recent work of Kapouleas Wiygul but you should check this.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Got it - if you want to copy this verbatim as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.